# How to apply different formulas depending on a condition?

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula

I have a ss with due dates, I also have a column with conditions of how that date should change.

For example I have a due date on column I, but in column N, I have "15th". This means that the date of the column I should change to the next 15th available in the calendar.
I have many different conditions in column N, so I had a formula =If.... with all the different conditions/formulas, but it's too long now so I can't keep adding new conditions. I think it should be a way of applyng a fomula to a cell based on a condition from another cell? I have tried everywhere to find how to do it, with no luck, so if someone can help me I will really appreciate it.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome to SO. The usual way is exactly like you say: adding different IFS, each with their own condition. I don't know how many conditions you have but maybe you should try to unify them in a single one using some maths. Can you add an example input and expected output based on different rules? We cannot help at all without knowing your rules.

Comment: have a list of conditions and use vlookup()

Comment: This is the formula I'm using atm: =IF(O2="10th",IF(DAY(I2)<=10,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),10),DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2)+1,10)),
IF(O2="1st and 3rd Friday of every month",IF(I2<I2-DAY(I2)+1+1*7-WEEKDAY(I2-DAY(I2)+8-6),I2-DAY(I2)+1+1*7-WEEKDAY(I2-DAY(I2)+8-6),IF(I2<I2-DAY(I2)+1+3*7-WEEKDAY(I2-DAY(I2)+8-6),I2-DAY(I2)+1+3*7-WEEKDAY(I2-DAY(I2)+8-6),(I2+10)-DAY((I2+10))+1+1*7-WEEKDAY((I2+10)-DAY((I2+10))+8-6))), ..... It doesn't fit here, but is something like that.

Comment: @ElisaRojas how many different rules are we talking about?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns At the moment I have 50 different rules, but it can be more over time.

Comment: If you got 50 different rules I'm afraid your best way is to use a macro to code all rules into one single global function. You'll need to code something in VBA for that (actually [Select Case statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/select-case-statement) might be really useful in your scenario.